# try to scrapy website on simple example but output null in json

Tags: python, scrapy

Learning scrapy try on a simple example, but not that 'simple' to me. I try couple hour from linux to windows. After "scrapy crawl tiantian -o items.json -t json", here "tiantian" is a name of spider, there nothing output and record in items.json. Here's the scripts, please help.

ITEM:

```
import scrapy

class MeijuItem(scrapy.Item):
    pass

class tiantianitem(scrapy.Item):

    name=scrapy.Field()
    link=scrapy.Field()
```

SPIDER:

```
import scrapy
from meiju.items import tiantianitem

class TiantianSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = "tiantian"
   allowed_domains = ["cn163.net/archives/18296"]
   start_urls = (
    'http://cn163.net/archives/18296/',
)

def parse(self, response):
    i=tiantianitem
    items=[]
    sites=response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[3]/div/p[2]/a')
    for site in sites:
        i['name']=site.xpath('/text()').extract()
        i['link']=site.xpath('/@href').extract()
        items.append(i)
    return items
```

SETTINGS:

```
BOT_NAME = 'meiju'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['meiju.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'meiju.spiders'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 2

COOKIES_ENABLED = False

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
}
```

Comment: There are few things that are wrong with your spider. First of all your start url doesn't even seem to exist and `allowed_domains` should contain domain part of the url only, so in your case it would be `allowed_domains = ["cn163.net"]`

Comment: Thanks for your inform, I modified the domain, still null output. Is that necessary to wirte the pipeline in order to have output?

Comment: thanks for you help. it works